# File data may have been lost excel apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

This question has been asked before but my issue is definitely different. I ran my program on two different machines, both mac and used Microsoft Excel mac version to open the Excel file. Oddly one machine works perfectly and the other gives me a "file data may have been lost". I pulled the program from my git account and confirmed it is the most recent version and I cleared my cache in my browser, but it is still giving me the same error before displaying a blank excel worksheet.

JobOrderGenerator

```
public class JobOrderGenerator {

    private OutputStream out;

    private int sheetNumber = 0;
    private HSSFWorkbook workbook;
    private HSSFSheet sheet;

    @Inject
    HttpServletResponse response;
    @Inject
    GenerateTemplate generateTemplate;

    public JobOrderGenerator(List<ShopOrder> shopOrder, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {

        this.response = response;   
        createWorkBook();
        createJobOrder(shopOrder);
        createFile();
    }

    private void createWorkBook() { 
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();              
    }

    private void createSheet(){     
        //String safeName = WorkbookUtil.createSafeSheetName(sheetName);
        sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        generatShopOrderTemplate();
    }

    private void generatShopOrderTemplate(){
        generateTemplate = new GenerateTemplate();
        generateTemplate.applyTemplate(workbook, sheet);
    }

    private void createJobOrder(List<ShopOrder> order) throws InvalidFormatException,
            IOException {

           //get current date time with Date()
           Date todaysDate = new Date();

        for(ShopOrder shopOrder: order){

            writeToSpecificCell(1, 1, sheetNumber, shopOrder.getPo_number()); // Po Number

            writeToSpecificCell(6, 3, sheetNumber, shopOrder.getPart_number()); // Part Number

            LocalDate date = shopOrder.getPo_due_date();
            String dateToString = date.toString();
            writeToSpecificCell(5, 7, sheetNumber, dateToString); // Due_Date
            writeToSpecificCell(2, 1, sheetNumber, todaysDate.toString());//todays date
            writeToSpecificCell(6, 7, sheetNumber,
                    Integer.toString(shopOrder.getPart_quantity())); // Part Quantity
            //writeToSpecificCell(1,2,sheetNumber, shopOrder.getMaterial); //Material
            writeToSpecificCell(7, 3, sheetNumber, shopOrder.getPart_decription()); // Part Description

            writeToSpecificCell(5,3,sheetNumber, shopOrder.getCustomer_name()); //Customer

            writeToSpecificCell(10, 1, sheetNumber, shopOrder.getMachine_number()); // Machine
            writeToSpecificCell(7, 7, sheetNumber, shopOrder.getMaterial_number()); // Material Number

            sheetNumber++;          
        }


    }

    private void writeToSpecificCell(int rowNumber, int cellNumber, int sheetNumber,
            String value) throws InvalidFormatException {


        createSheet();
        try {

            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);

            HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);
            HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellNumber);

            if (cell == null) {
                cell = row.createCell(cellNumber);
            }
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue(value);

        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {

            System.out.println("writeToSpecificCell class is returning null ");
            ex.getStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void createFile(){

        // Set Excel File Name
        String fileName = "JobTicket.xls";
        // Set HTT
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename="
                + fileName);

        try {
            out = response.getOutputStream();
            workbook.write(out);
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Template Creator

```
@Named
public class GenerateTemplate {

    public HSSFWorkbook applyTemplate(HSSFWorkbook workbook, HSSFSheet sheet) {
        //total rows to create (starts at 0)
        int totalRows = 26;//27 total rows
        sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 4300);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(8, 3000);

        //create sheet rows
        for(int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
            sheet.createRow(i);
        }

        //Fonts
        //Bold Header Font
        HSSFFont boldHeaderFont = workbook.createFont();
        boldHeaderFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        boldHeaderFont.setFontName("Broadway");
        boldHeaderFont.setItalic(true);
        boldHeaderFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 16);

        //Default Font
        HSSFFont defaultFont = workbook.createFont();
        defaultFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL);

        //Bold Font
        HSSFFont boldFont = workbook.createFont();
        boldFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);

      //Bold blue Font
        HSSFFont boldBlueFont = workbook.createFont();
        boldBlueFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        boldBlueFont.setColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index);



      //Bold blue Tall Font
        HSSFFont boldBlueTallFont = workbook.createFont();
        boldBlueTallFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        boldBlueTallFont.setColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index);
        boldBlueTallFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 14);
     //Styles
        //Bold Header
        HSSFCellStyle boldHeaderStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        boldHeaderStyle.setFont(boldHeaderFont);
        boldHeaderStyle.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        //Center
        HSSFCellStyle centerStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        centerStyle.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        //Bold
        HSSFCellStyle boldStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        boldStyle.setFont(boldFont);
        //Grey Background fill
        HSSFCellStyle greyFillStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        greyFillStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex());
        greyFillStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        //Centered Bold Blue Style
        HSSFCellStyle centeredBoldBlueStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        centeredBoldBlueStyle.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        centeredBoldBlueStyle.setFont(boldBlueFont);
      //Centered Bold Blue Tall Style
        HSSFCellStyle centeredBoldBlueTallStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        centeredBoldBlueTallStyle.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        centeredBoldBlueTallStyle.setFont(boldBlueTallFont);


        //Merged Cells
        //Name and Address merged
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,2,8));
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,1,2,8));
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(2,2,2,8));
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(3,3,2,8));
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(4,4,2,8));

        //Customer merged
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(5,5,3,5));

        //Part Merged
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(6,6,3,5));

        //Create template cells
            //column 1
            sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("Job No.");
            sheet.createRow(1).createCell(0).setCellValue("P.O. No.");
            sheet.createRow(2).createCell(0).setCellValue("Date");

            HSSFRow row;
            HSSFCell cell;

            //Name and Address Info
            row = sheet.getRow(1);
            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue("Hillcrest Tool & Die");
            cell.setCellStyle(boldHeaderStyle);

            row = sheet.getRow(2);
            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue("807 Jones Rd, Paragould AR");
            cell.setCellStyle(centerStyle);

            row = sheet.getRow(3);
            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue("(870)573-6881");
            cell.setCellStyle(centerStyle);

            //Grey Background Cells
            row = sheet.getRow(0);
            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellStyle(greyFillStyle);

            row = sheet.getRow(4);
            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellStyle(greyFillStyle);

            row = sheet.getRow(8);
            cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellStyle(greyFillStyle);

            row = sheet.getRow(8);
            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellStyle(greyFillStyle);

            //Customer centered
            row = sheet.getRow(5);
            cell = row.createCell(3);
            cell.setCellStyle(centeredBoldBlueStyle);

            //part centered
            row = sheet.getRow(6);
            cell = row.createCell(3);
            cell.setCellStyle(centeredBoldBlueTallStyle);


            sheet.getRow(5).createCell(2).setCellValue("Customer");
            sheet.getRow(5).createCell(6).setCellValue("Due Date");
            sheet.getRow(6).createCell(2).setCellValue("Part No.");
            sheet.getRow(6).createCell(6).setCellValue("Quantity");
            sheet.createRow(7).createCell(0).setCellValue("PARTIAL");
            sheet.getRow(7).createCell(2).setCellValue("Part Description");
            sheet.getRow(7).createCell(6).setCellValue("Material");
            sheet.getRow(9).createCell(3).setCellValue("Initials");
            sheet.getRow(9).createCell(4).setCellValue("Date");
            sheet.getRow(9).createCell(5).setCellValue("Operation");
            sheet.getRow(9).createCell(6).setCellValue("Qty");
            sheet.getRow(9).createCell(7).setCellValue("Total");
            sheet.getRow(9).createCell(8).setCellValue("Hours");
            sheet.createRow(10).createCell(0).setCellValue("Machine");
            sheet.getRow(10).createCell(1).setCellValue("LASER / PLASMA");
            sheet.getRow(17).createCell(1).setCellValue("BEND / MILL");


           return workbook;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it work perfectly on the windows machine? also what version of Excel are you using on both? It might be worth seeing if you can generate a file on one machine and open it on the other another.

Comment: Are you using the same version of Apache POI on both machines?

Comment: Using Excel version 14.5.2 and I am using the same version of apache POI because I downloaded it from my GIT account. I have not yet tried it on a windows machine yet.

Answer (score 0):

Change everything from **HSSFWorkbook** to **XSSFWorkbook**. Because **HSSFWorkbook** object creates **XLS** which doesn't support generating negative values and also it's old so use **XSSFWorkbook** which creates **XLSX**.